# Merge two list items based on single value in the list collection in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, c#-4.0

```
     List<Person> persons = null;
                persons = new List<Person>();
                persons.Add(new Person
                {
                    Id = 1,
                    FirstName = "Chris",
                    LastName = "Cummings",
                    phn = 111223333,
                    comment="test"
                }); 
                persons.Add(new Person
                {
                    Id = 2,
                    FirstName = "Chris",
                    LastName = "Cummings",
                    phn = 987654321,
                    comment=""
                });
                persons.Add(new Person
                {
                    Id = 3,
                    FirstName = "John",
                    LastName = "Steinbeck",
                    phn = 111223333,
                    comment = "dfdf"
                }); 
persons.Add(new Person
            {
                Id = 4,
                FirstName = "fgg",
                LastName = "hgh",
                phn = 545,
                comment = ""
            });
```

from the above list i would like to display below data

if the firstname and lastname match for any person that person must contain comments otherwise remove the other person who doesn't have the comments

```
    Id = 1,
                    FirstName = "Chris",
                    LastName = "Cummings",
                    phn = 111223333,
                    comment="test"
    Id = 3,
                    FirstName = "John",
                    LastName = "Steinbeck",
                    phn = 111223333,
                    comment = "dfdf"
Id = 4,
                    FirstName = "fgg",
                    LastName = "hgh",
                    phn = 545,
                    comment = ""
```

Comment: I can only see 1 list

Comment: @Sujit.Warrier The question does say "merge two list items" and not 2 lists.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `GroupBy` and filter results after that with `SelectMany` function

```
var result = 
    persons.GroupBy(p => new { p.FirstName, p.LastName })
           .SelectMany(g => g.Where(p => string.IsNullOrEmpty(p.Comment) == false));
```

In case you want keep person which doesn't have matched persons and have empty comment you can add condition `group.Count() == 1`

```
var result = 
    persons.GroupBy(p => new { p.FirstName, p.LastName })
           .SelectMany(g => 
                      {
                          var isSingle = g.Count() == 1;
                          return g.Where(p => isSingle || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(p.Comment))
                      });
```

Comment: Just edited my question with new person  detail in that case it was not working this logic. @Fabio

Comment: @User333, second approach will work for your new (edited) requirements. I was expecting that ;)

Comment: Second approach is returning all the values @Fabio

Comment: @User333, no, second approach will work. I think you have something wrong in the `GroupBy` code, because it seems in your try `GroupBy` returns groups with only one person

Comment: You're right! I misunderstood the requirements, I'll remove my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
//Union the persons and use the comparer class

var result =   persons.Union(persons, new PersonComparer()).Where(e=> !string.IsNullOrEmpty( e.comment));
//Use the below comparer class

public class PersonComparer : IEqualityComparer<Person>
{

    public bool Equals(Person x, Person y)
    {
        return x.FirstName == y.FirstName && x.LastName == y.LastName;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Person obj)
    {
        return obj.FirstName.GetHashCode() + obj.LastName.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```